# Terraform Enterprise is not triggered for commits in bitbucket

Tags: version-control, terraform, bitbucket, terraform-enterprise

I have a TFE workspace with proper Version Control details.
Whenever I commit any change in Bitbucket, nothing is triggered in TFE.

[image]

But if I change the branch in TFE version control and change it back again, I can see a plan getting queued up for the latest commit in the branch.

So every time I need to run, I have to change my branch in TFE Version control.
Any pointers for its resolution?

Comment: This means the webhook transmission from your Bitbucket to TFE is broken (but not because of networking reasons). You need to begin troubleshooting in that direction.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I couldn't find any setting for this in TFE or bitbucket..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, TFE service account needed admin access to bitbucket for the version control integration to work.